# Update DOM with $scope property using an Angular Directive - as soon as the directive runs (without waiting for an event)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

If you look at this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/rodhartzell/u4zVd/1/

You can see that the model $scope.bar is not accounted for by the directive, until one of the subscribed events is handled.  Do you know of a way to make the directive recognize the model as soon as it binds?

```
            element.keyup(scope.onEdit)
            .keydown(scope.onEdit)
            .focus(scope.onEdit)
            .live('input paste', scope.onEdit);
        element.on('ngChange', scope.onEdit);
```

Comment: Did you tried scope.$apply()?

Comment: Maybe I did not phrase this question very well.  What I would like is for the directive to see the model state in the controller and react accordingly.

Comment: As you can see in the fiddle the directive does not realize that the model has been bound to the element so the "Characters remaining" value does not get updated.

Comment: @RodHartzell see my completed answer with demo. Should be exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have approached the whole issue differently. Rather than binding the event, I would setup a watch on the length like this:

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/aSAdUroy/1/edit)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.bar = 'something';
});

app.directive('myMaxlength', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: { bar: "=ngModel" },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var counterElem = angular.element('<span>Characters remaining: {{charsRemaining}}</span>');
      $compile(counterElem)(scope);
      element.parent().append(counterElem);

      scope.$watch(
        function() {
          return scope.bar.length; 
        },
        function(newLength) {
          scope.charsRemaining = attrs.myMaxlength - newLength;
        }
      );
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Perfect!  I appreciate the detailed response.  I have marked this as the answer.  Thank you.

Comment: @RodHartzell awesome! I love Angular =D